# The requested URL /task was not found on this server. laravel/quickstart

Tags: .htaccess, laravel

I recently started the tutorial 'quickstart' of laravel and I got stuck at this error:

> The requested URL /task was not found on this server.

```
env:wamp
code:
DocumentRoot: 'E:/workspace/laravelapp/public"

    Route::post('/task',function(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withError($validator);
    }
    //create task
    $task = new task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

I tried to use `url()` and I find that if the url has 'index.php', it works, otherwise it doesn't work. So I think the problem caused by `.htaccess` probably, but what I tried failed.

Comment: enable mod_rewrite in your apache

Comment: sentence structure, code and quote blocks

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file you can add a constant.

DOMAIN = http://localhost/laravelapp/public/  ***(or how your localhost path is)***

Then in your form add action `<form action="{{env('DOMAIN')}}/task"`> .

Because i think in your case if you have only `<form action="/task">`it will redirect to http://localhost/task .

Comment: Thanks .Really,the request will  redirect to http://localhost/task .i tried to solve the question in your way,then report error：‘undefined domain’.i think the constant  cannot  be availbale in view of file. should i render a variable to view via 'view()'?

Comment: Sorry , i edited the code. The "/task" in the action attr was inside curly brackets. Should be out. Hope it works this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of enthusiasts,the question have been solved.
1.check mod_rewrite status of apache;
2.check configuration of 'Options FollowSymLinks  AllowOverride none',you need to modify it as 'Options FollowSymLinks  AllowOverride all'.
3.edit your .htaccess,exp:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

now,restart your apache,it works.

:)